# Android How to Connect to Remote Server, Execute php file and retrieve data

Tags: android

I am trying to connect the Remote Server and the Use the database. I don't know how to connect to the Server and Execute the `PHP` file. Please help. I am using JSON to display the data in the `PHP` file.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a `webservice` at your server side, then you need to call your web service from android app, the you can access your database

Comment: Yes I have. but i don't know how to connect. Is there any article for connection for Server.

Comment: what type of webservice you are using

Comment: Actually my friend has a Domain I don't know what type. May be its REST

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to connect to a server using php then you can do this task by using a `webview`.

Ex: Connecting a MySQL database in php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('host','user_name','password','database')
or die('Error in connecting database');
//Do stuff in your case you echo json array/object
?>
```

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) link and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) link have very good examples how to fetch data from `json` encoded PHP files. I hope these references can solve your problem.

Comment: I wrote php files. I stored in server also. The Problem is how to execute and Retrieve data from that and Show in My Android App. Php files showing result also.

Comment: Ok let me know your URL where you have your php file.

Comment: HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost hpost=new HttpPost(MY_URL);
   HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(hpost);
   HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
   isr=entity.getContent();  IS THIS THE RIGHT WAY...

Comment: No. This is not the right way unless you want all the content starting from <html> to </html> the whole page content will be copied. Try using webview. Simply drag a webview to your xml file and give an ID then use the above code. It works for me everytime

Comment: while executing my above code i got Error javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate. Using JSON I am retrieving data. Not using WebView to display my data.

Comment: Then you should have mentioned it clearly in your question. wait a minute while I edit my solution

Comment: But this error 'javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate' is not allowing to execute my php file. That JSON Articles were Good.Thanks.

Comment: Then this is not an issue in your android. It is related to your web server. If you can provide the link then I could help you more regarding this